# dockerhub build fails requirements.txt not found

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am building a Docker image for some python packages, for which I using `requirements.txt` to install all python packages by pip.

I have all Dockerfile, requirements.txt, and related python scripts in the subfolder of my GitHub repo.

```
-> Main repo
---> folder
    --> some python scripts
    --> docker_folder
       --> Dockerfile
       --> requirements.txt
---> some files
---> some files
```

I have built the image locally which works fine but while configuring autobuild in Docker Hub it throws an error by stating that `requirements.txt not found` but it found Dockerfile. I have changed the Dockerfile location in the build setting on Docker Hub by:`folder/docker_folder/Dockerfile`.

I think the main problem lies in the Build configuration setting. Any help? Thanks.

logfile from Dockerhub built:

```
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'19.03.8', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2020-03-11T01:24:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.40', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'afacb8b7f0', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.12.17'}}, {u'Version': u'1.2.13', u'Name': u'containerd', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429'}}, {u'Version': u'1.0.0-rc10', u'Name': u'runc', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd'}}, {u'Version': u'0.18.0', u'Name': u'docker-init', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'fec3683'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2020-03-11T01:24:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.40
Platform: {u'Name': u'Docker Engine - Community'}
Version: 19.03.8
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: afacb8b7f0
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.12.17
Starting build of index.docker.io/darsh3/python_drl:latest...
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.8
---> 8f6adb7689b5
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR ${PWD}/..
---> Running in 516d190b493f
Removing intermediate container 516d190b493f
---> e948c6e6f641
Step 3/5 : COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder968608568/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the directory structure you show, if you run

```sh
docker build -f folder/docker_folder/Dockerfile "Main repo"
```

then the source of all `COPY` commands is relative to the `"Main repo"` directory.

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
# Needs to COPY from the directory relative to the `docker build`
# context directory argument
COPY folder/docker_folder/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You might consider moving the `requirements.txt` file up to the top level of your repository or perhaps the directory containing the Python scripts, since it's a standard Python packaging file and not Docker-specific.  If the only Docker-specific thing you have is the `Dockerfile` then putting it in the top-level directory is fairly common as well.

```sh
# If the Dockerfile is in the named directory, no -f option is needed
docker build "Main repo/folder"
```

```sh
# If the file is in the named directory, just use its name without a path
COPY requirements.txt .
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the relativity of the path. Locally everything was fine but the mistake I was doing in DockerHub was in build-contex: `/folder/docker_file/` and docker file: `folder/docker_folder/Dockerfile`. The correct way is build-contex: `/folder/docker_folder/` and docker file: `Dockerfile` as in Dockerhub Dockerfile path is relative to build-context.

Answer (score 1):

Please use COPY command like below. Error occurs because you might be building image using `.` context

```
COPY folder/docker_folder/requirements.txt ./
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and tried to build locally but still, it can not find `requirements.txt`. I tried to build from `./main_repo` terminal by `docker build -t test ./folder/docker_folder/`

Comment: Yes, i was using COPY by `.` context. log : `COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat folder/docker_folder/requirements.txt: file does not exist`